# Arduino UNO connected to HM-10 returning � to AT commands

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno, hm-10

I have my HM-10 connected to my Arduino UNO and I'm trying AT commands. I keep getting � no matter what command I send. I am new to Arduino and have used http://www.blueluminance.com/HM-10-as-iBeacon.pdf guide for setting up the chip. Here is the code I'm using for the board

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(0, 1); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
  // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.println("Goodnight moon!");

 // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
 mySerial.begin(9600);
 mySerial.println("Hello, world?");
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
 if (mySerial.available())
     Serial.write(mySerial.read());
 if (Serial.available())
     mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `mySerial.write(Serial.read());` to `mySerial.println(Serial.read());`

Serial.write makes not conversion of the data, whereas Serial.print converts to characters.  If this works, probably switch the `Serial.write` to the same.